# Not able to fetch data/Response on Success of Jquery.Ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, webmethod

**Hi people, I am craving myself from past 3 days and I just couldn't find the way to access json response seen on my browser**

[image: Json response seen on firebug]

**Here is my Ajax code :**

```
$("[id*=btnModalPopup]").live("click", function () {

    $("#tblCustomers tbody tr").remove();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CallDataThroughJquery.aspx/GetLeadDetails",
        data: '{}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
        alert("Hi Json");
        alert(data.Leadno);  // **Says data.leadno is undefined**

        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {  // **here I am going some where wrong**
         //**cannot catch response. Help!**

        }))

        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
});
```

Please help me on this.. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: can your post your json response too here

Comment: Here is the json response :

[{"__type":"WEBFORMS_CallDataThroughJquery+LeadDetails","Leadno":"HR30082009000227","StatusName":"Follow Up","ExpiryDays":4}]

Comment: Can you post the response, please?

Comment: I did it already, check my comments above.

Comment: `data[0].Leadno`, you are returning an array

Comment: Thanks Victory data[0].Leadno worked!!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your JSON is an array with an object. Try data[0].Leadno

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "CallDataThroughJquery.aspx/GetLeadDetails",
    data: '{}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
    alert("Hi Json");
    alert(data.d[0]['Leadno']);  // **Says data.leadno is undefined**

    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {  // **here I am going some where wrong**
     //**cannot catch response. Help!**

    }))

    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

Try your alert with 'data.d[0]['Leadno']'.

Comment: @Angel, You can do that in either way.